# delete spreadsheet on google drive from website

Tags: php, mysql, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am using a MySql database and google spreadsheets together. Each record in my MySql database has a corresponding google spreadsheet for aditional datas. On my website I have displayed the datas and included the spreatsheet by iframe.

From my website I edit and delete the records by php-script. After deleting a record from my database I go to google drive an delete the corresponding spreadsheet.

Is it posible, to delete the spreadsheet as well with the same php script from my website? If yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely you can. You may create an Apps Script and publish it as a webapp. Now you can call the wepapp URL from PHP using curl and pass the ID of the spreadsheet to the Weapp. App will take the ID and do the required action. Webapp code will look something like

```
function doGet(e){
  var ssId = e.parameters.ssid;
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(ssId);
  DriveApp.removeFile(file);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('File removed').setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
}
```

For more details, check Apps Script Content Service.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content